Omniscript/Flexcard and SF Fields
Is there a way or tool ​​that can extract or find out where the fields in omniscript/flexcard are mapped to SF fields? Thanks!

I haven't worked with Omniscript, but I'm guessing it's in the Omniscript metadata component or related components, so you'd need Visual Studio Code or a devops tool like Copado / Gearset to extract the metadata and view it.
